# what are good references for learning about vector bundles and their sheaves of sections?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, representation-theory, manifolds

I am a beginner in representation theory and algebraic geometry, so that references giving clear explanations of things like the tautological line bundle on $\mathbb P^n$, its dual, and the associated sheaves of sections $\mathcal O(-1)$ and $\mathcal O(1)$ would be especially welcome.

I have some difficulty in understanding the sentence in the first paragraph of section 9.3 (page 140) in the book of Fulton clearly: There is a general procedure for producing representations as sections of a line bundle on a homogeneous space on page 140 (the first paragraph of section 9.3) of the book Young Tableaux by Fulton: http://books.google.com/books?id=U9vZal2HCcoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=young+tableaux&source=bl&ots=xxxzyLzSra&sig=KmvmON6e4Xli3Fz2b0g2S5j6XTE&hl=en&ei=vHkjTd_CCoWBlAemzLigDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false. I am sorry that I do not know how to make a good link such that the link is not so long.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The friendliest introduction to complex vector bundles on complex manifolds might be *Complex Manifolds, Vector Bundles and Hodge Theory* by Brylinski and Toth.

On the subject which interests you (link with representation theory), I recommend the article *The Borel-Weil theorem for complex projective space* by M.Eastwood and J.Sawon in the book *Invitations to Geometry and Topology* (Oxford Graduate Texts In Mathematics #7). The article is self-contained and fairly elementary.

You could also look at the nice book by Joseph Taylor, *Several Complex Variables*, published by the AMS, Graduate  Studies In Mathematics #46. Borel-Weil is carefully handled there, with all the necessary preliminaries.

Comment: Hi elgeorges, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

A brief introduction to line bundles (and divisors) on schemes is available at http://people.fas.harvard.edu/~amathew/linebund.pdf, although it is very rough. This covers things like the tautological line bundle on $\mathbb{P}^n$ and the sheaves $\mathcal{O}(n)$. In particular, it gives the correspondence (as in Hartshorne II.6) between Weil and Cartier divisors on regular noetherian integral schemes (such as projective space over a field). I don't know if this is completely relevant to what you need, but it may (or may not) be useful for your initial questions. Having not read Fulton's book, I can't answer your specific question.

Comment: Hi Akhil, thank you very much.

Comment: The link needs to be updated with the UChicago address.